# Viewing Yorda's subtitles

Tags: ps3, ico

I missed out on playing this on the PS2 and have just finished it on the PS3 and thought it was ace!

I remember reading somewhere that on the 2nd play through Yorda's subtitles were translated but I've just started a 2nd play through and this isn't the case for me.

Is there something I need to do to enable this or was it not carried over to the PS3 version?

Answer (score 2):

On PS2, the second playthrough [does not translate Yorda's words for the U.S. version](http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_bonuses_not_found_in_and_changes_from_the_U.S._version_of_Ico#Yorda.27s_speech_translated). I would assume this carries over to the PS3 release, lest you'd see the translation now.

You can translate the script yourself using [Team ICO's runic language](http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_language_used_in_Ico), or read [this user-translated script](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/367472-ico/faqs/16220) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Yorda's Speech Script).

Comment: I got there in the end. I had to load my completed game rather than start a "new game". Thanks for the useful links.